# Write a text file from Oracle APEX application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to write a text file from Oracle APEX application. (Release 4.2)  I found the code below, but I keep getting the error ORA-29280 invalid directory path.
The directory specified is a directory for which I have write access.  I made a file in notepad and saved it to this directory.

Maybe I need to be able to browse for the output directory.  Does APEX have a file browse for output files?

What can you tell me?  Thanks.

My code

```
Declare
   v_input_record   varchar2(600);
   p_dir varchar2(200); 
   p_file varchar2(50); 
   l_output utl_file.file_type; 
   l_amt number default 32000; 

cursor cur_go_thru_AD_INPUT
  is select COUNTY_INPUT_RECORD
  from ad_county_input_file
    order by county_input_file_id_seq;

begin
    p_dir := 'C:\Windows\Temp';
    p_file := 'SoS-Output.asc';
    l_output := utl_file.fopen(p_dir, p_file, 'w', 32767);

  open cur_go_thru_AD_INPUT;
  LOOP
     FETCH cur_go_thru_AD_INPUT
          INTO v_input_record;
     EXIT WHEN cur_go_thru_AD_INPUT%NOTFOUND;

    utl_file.put(l_output, v_input_record ); 
    utl_file.fflush(l_output);

  END LOOP;

utl_file.new_line(l_output); 
utl_file.fclose(l_output);
```

end;

Comment: maybe first try to create directory

Answer (score 0):

maybe first try to create directory

```
create or replace directory DIRECTORY_NAME as 'C:\Windows\Temp';
```

and then call it

```
utl_file.fopen('DIRECTORY_NAME', p_file, 32767);
```

Comment: I was told that it cannot be a directory on the client PC, which is what I wanted.

Comment: utl_file cannot write to the client machine, only the database server.

Comment: but there is a way to write to the client pc, here is a full tutorial: http://dba-oracle.com/t_oracle:__write_a_file_to_to_a_client_pc.htm